# Complexity for finding the maximum independent set of a graph

Tags: graph, greedy

Can anyone answer me what is the complexity for this method which finds the maximum independent set of a graph?

```
Greedy(G):
S = {}
While G is not empty:    Let v be a node with minimum degree in G
    S = union(S, {v})
    remove v and its neighbors from G
return S
```

Comment: You will go through all the nodes that are not visited and perform a DFS or BFS starting from it and mark the visited nods as visited. So the complexity is O(|V|), because you will take each vertex only once.

Comment: Choosing v with minimum degree requires priority queue or sorting. Usually that requires O(|V|log|V|). Since nodes are sorted by degree, that can be done with bucket sort in O(|V|).